# Rails: Call sign_out(@user) from a background worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sidekiq

I want to sign_out a given user from a background job? E.g. sign out a given user fom a Sidekiq background worker. Any idea how I can access the method sign_out from the worker?

```
class SessionWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(user_id)
      # user = User.find(user_id)
      # sign_out(user) if user
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but:

I don't think this is possible because when you run code from a background worker, that code is executed in a different context than your web application and thus has no access to the warden session where the login is 'registrated'.

Comment: But I have access on all Rails models. So, why it is not possible to code some lines to sign out from the model. e.g. 

`u = User.find(1)
u.sign_out
`